# Define Powershell variable to have a value of a list

Tags: powershell

I have some variables as below:

```
$a = "string1"
$b = "string2"
$c = "string3"
```

Now i want to define a variable $list to with all of the content from $a,$b,$c to look like this:

```
$list = "
a: string1
b: string2
c: string3
"
```

how can i do that?

*** Edit: the content of the list must be EXACT like i wrote, that means, the part like "a: " b: ", ... must be the same too

Comment: `$list` as you've defined it is not a list data type, just a multi-line string.  Do you want a 'real' list or just something that looks like a list to the user.  What is it you want to do with the 'list' you create?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you don't want an actual list, but a string with a listing of variables. A multiline string with the names and values of your variables could be defined like this:

```
$list = @"
a: ${a}
b: ${b}
c: ${c}
"@
```

Another, more dynamic, option would be something like this:

```
$list = 'a', 'b', 'c' | ForEach-Object {
    "${_}: $(Get-Variable $_ -ValueOnly)"
} | Out-String
```

where you specify a list with the variable names, output strings containing each variable name and the corresponding value, and merge those into a single string at the end.

Comment: Great! I like it! ++

Answer (score 2):

Powershell has '[arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6)':

> "An array is a data structure that is designed to store a collection
>   of items. The items can be the same type or different types."

In your case, if you have variables already, you can include them in an array:

```
$myarray = $a, $b, $c
Write-Host $myarray
```

or

```
$myarray = @($a, $b, $c)
Write-Host $myarray
```

or you can create an associative array for enter your key-value elements:

```
$otherarray = @{}            # create en empty array
$otherarray['a'] = 'string1' # add key-value pairs
$otherarray['b'] = 'string2'
$otherarray['c'] = 'string3'
Write-Host $otherarray.c     #print in console example
```

**Edit:** by your example I recommended arrays because I think it's a simple use case, but if you will modify it frecuently, better use [System.Collection.ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$mylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$mylist.add($a)
$mylist.add($b)
$mylist.add($c)
$Write-Host $mylist
```

Comment: Hi Sir. I mean in the list content, the name 'a', 'b', and 'c' also have to keep. It has to be exact like i wrote in the content of the list. That means the parts such as : "a: ", b: ", ... must be kept too

Comment: Take a look to the @Ansgar's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443564/define-powershell-variable-to-have-a-value-of-a-list/50445497#50445497

Comment: Thank you too, for the info of arrays and list. I'm new after all

Answer (score 1):

```
[string[]]$list = "string1","string2","string3"
```

#### Edit:

I did not read your question fully, here's an example of a hash table with key=value pairs:

```
$a = "string1"
$b = "string2"
$c = "string3"

$list = @{
a = $a
b = $b
c = $c
}
```

Ultimately it depends on whether you know how to use the construct, and what you're using it for. There are many ways to achieve a simple list/array/table of 3 strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList** to create a list and use it.
eg:

```
$a = "string1"
$b = "string2"
$c = "string3"

$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$list.Add($a)
$list.Add($b)
$list.Add($c)
```

Now $list[1] gives string2.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hi Sir. I mean in the list content, the name 'a', 'b', and 'c' also have to keep. It has to be exact like i wrote in the content of the list. That means the parts such as : "a: ", b: ", ... must be kept too

Comment: I see. you need a dictionary sort of thing. Please refer to this @ansgar's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50445497/9423480

Comment: Thank you too for the instruction of using list. I am new to powershell after all

Answer (score 0):

I suspect other answers have given you what you're after already.  However, here are other solutions for different interpretations of your question...

---

If you wish to have the list populated with the values which are in `a`, `b`, and `c` at run time, you can do this:

```
$a = "string1"
$b = "string2"
$c = "string3"

$list = @('a','b','c') | Get-Variable | ForEach-Object{'{0}: {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Value}
$list
```

i.e. this finds the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` and populates `list` with strings based on the variable's name and value formatted as `name: value`.

---

Alternatively, if you wish to populate a list with a single "here-string" (i.e. a string which may be multi-line) split to be one item per line, you could do this:

```
$list = @'
a: string1
b: string2
c: string3
'@ -split '[\r\n]+'
$list.Count #prove that our list contains 3 items rather than 1 multi line item
$list # show the contents of the array
```

This takes the multi-line string and splits it on line breaks (using a regex to ensure it treats different potential line endings the same way, and skips over multiple sequential line breaks to avoid creating blank entries between items).

---

Finally, if you wanted to populate variables `a`, `b`, and `c` from the list, you could use something like this:

```
$list = @(
    'a: string1',
    'b: string2',
    'c: string3'
)

$list | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^\s*(?<VarName>[^\:]+)\s*:\s*(?<VarValue>.*)$') {
        Write-Verbose ('Name: {0}; Value {1}' -f $Matches.VarName, $Matches.VarValue)
        New-Variable -Name $Matches.VarName -Value $Matches.VarValue -Force
    }
}
$a
$b
$c
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a hashtable is what you are looking for:

```
$list = @{}
$list.a = 'string1'
$list.b = 'string2'
$list.c = 'string3'

foreach( $item in $list ) {
  # do something
}

# get content of hash:

$var = $list['a']

# or

$var = $list.a
```